# VS 2015 MSBuild Deploy Database Project Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, database-project

I'm having an issue using VS 2015 MSBuild to deploy a database project via the command line.  The issue is I need to be able to use MSBuild with 14.0 only, without VS 2013 installed.

I'm using 14.0 MSBuild at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

The following works because I also have Visual Studio 2013 installed with the appropriate SQL Server Data Tools:

`MSBUILD "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\temp\Testing\TestProject\TestProject.sqlproj" /t:build "/p:Platform=AnyCPU" /t:deploy "/p:TargetConnectionString=Data Source=localhost;IntegratedSecurity=True" /p:TargetDatabase=TestDeployDb /p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`

However, if I change "VisualStudioVersion" to "14.0 for VS 2015, I get an error:

`Deploy error Deploy72002: Unable to connect to master or target server 'TestDeployDb'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'TestDeployDb'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to [Cole Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7012228/cole-wu) for saying my connection string was invalid, but his answer didn't work for me out of the box.  For some reason my connection string was* valid for 12.0 but not for 14.0.

The issue ended up being that I had `IntegartedSecurity` rather than `Integrated Security`, which broke my command when moving to 14.0

Here is the final that worked:

```
MSBUILD "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\temp\Testing\TestProject\TestProject.sqlproj" /t:build "/p:Platform=AnyCPU" /t:deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=True" /p:TargetDatabase="TestDeployDb" /p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

Comment: I am glad to know you solved this problem and thanks for sharing the solution. Please mark it as an answer, It will be very beneficial for other community members who have the similar questions.

Comment: Will do.  There is a "waiting period" since it is my answer.  So I will mark it when I can.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I create a demo and reproduce your issue on my side, you use an incorrect connection string. please modify your command like this:

```
MSBUILD "C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\temp\Testing\TestProject\TestProject.sqlproj" /t:build "/p:Platform=AnyCPU" /t:deploy /p:TargetConnectionString="Data Source=localhost;IntegratedSecurity=True" /p:TargetDatabase="TestDeployDb" /p:Configuration=Release /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```